# pyqt4 Setting QDateEdit value in Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4

I am copying a date value from a table to a QDateEdit in a dialog prior to launching the dialog. When I do this, the date format changes from "yyyy-MM-dd" to "dd/MM/yy" in the dialog. This happens in Linux not in OSx.
My Code:

```
class BuildRecordEditorDialog(QDialog, Ui_brePartEditDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__((self))
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.breDueDateEditor.setDisplayFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
        self.brePickDateEditor.setDisplayFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')

# In another Module

        buildRecordEditDialog = BuildRecordEditorDialog()  # Create an edit dialog

        brUi = buildRecordEditDialog
        brUi.setupUi(buildRecordEditDialog)
        brUi.breDeleteLabel.hide()    # This is not a delete so hide the delete message
        brUi.brePartNoEditor.setText(selectedPart[1].text())  # Pre-load defaults from selected data
        brUi.breDescriptionEditor.setText(selectedPart[2].text())
        brUi.breQuantityEditor.setText(selectedPart[3].text())
        brUi.breDueDateEditor.setDate(QtCore.QDate.fromString(selectedPart[4].text(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
        brUi.brePickDateEditor.setDate(QtCore.QDate.fromString(selectedPart[5].text(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

---

I am using pyqt4, Python 3.5.4, Ubuntu Linux

I have changed the locale setting for Time to: LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8" but it hasn't helped.

As a side note the brUi.breDeleteLabel.hide() setting is not respected either.

Answer (score 0):

No answers forthcoming so I did a work around. I converted the dates returned from the dialog from the bad format to the one I wanted and then processed them. User sees a different format but enters data with a date picker so all-in-all it will do.